# CSS/HTML complex shape

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

What's the best way to create the following shape?[image]

Comment: One regular div, and another one with border radius on top of it?

Comment: Looks to me like you've done a great job already... Oh, you mean in code? Have you tried anything?

Comment: Does your image represent three separate columns of text?

Comment: @Rounin yep it's 3 cols ideally. One for the circle and 2 for the sides. I could place the circle behind the band, but I'm not sure how to deal with their common border.

Comment: For the curves you should look at `SVG` or `CSS3 border-radius`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check following codepen

```
  <div class="bar">
     <div class="left">
       left Text
  </div> 

 <div class="cirlce">
    Circle
  </div>

 <div class="right">
   Right Text
 </div> 
</div>
```

CSS

```
.bar{
  margin-top:40px;
  width:100%;
  background:#ddd;
  height:80px;
  position:relative;
text-align:center;
}

.cirlce{
  width:140px;
  height:140px;
  background:#ccc;
  margin:0 auto;
  position:absolute;
  top:-30px;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  border-radius:50%
}

.left{
  left:0;
  position: absolute;
}

.right{
  right:0;
  position: absolute;
}
```

http://codepen.io/sajiddesigner/pen/NAORAv

Comment: Thanks @OptimumCreative, I've slightly modified your version here to achieve my needs [codepen](http://codepen.io/supertrall/pen/NAOaBV)

Comment: Happy that I have helped some one. Also I am happy to see your progress. Best of luck

Answer (score 7):

You could do this with one element and `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements.

```css
.el {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
  background: #89C3EE;
  margin: 50px 150px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 3px solid #6295DC;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.el:before,
.el:after {
  content: 'Text';
  position: absolute;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  background: #89C3EE;
  border-top: 3px solid #6295DC;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #6295DC;
}
.el:before {
  width: 150px;
  left: -143px;
}
.el:after {
  right: -94px;
}
```

```html
<div class="el">Text</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to have 3 separate `divs` and give the middle one a `border-radius`.

As you can see from the snippet below, this will enable you to include multiple paragraphs in each column (should you need them).

**Example:**

```css
div {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
width: 29vw;
padding: 2vw 1vw;
color: rgb(255,255,255);
font-size: 1vw;
background-color: rgb(255,0,0);
vertical-align: middle;
}

div p {
position: relative;
z-index: 12;
width: 22vw;
margin: 1vw auto;
}

div:nth-of-type(2) {
left: -7.5vw;
height: 26vw;
padding-top: 4vw;
text-align: center;
border-radius: 50%;
}

div:nth-of-type(2) p {
width: 15vw;
}

div:nth-of-type(3) {
left: -15vw;
text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
<p>Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>

<div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
<p>Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>

<div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
<p>Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
```